# CS1061: "IEnumerable<DB-entity-model>" does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending()'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core-5.0

Db model: root/ Entities/ ThreadEntity.cs .

root/ Data/ IThreadEntity.cs

```
IEnumerable<ThreadEntity> GetLatestThreads(int amount); // to get/ load at once.
```

root/ Controllers/ ThreadController.cs , HomeController.cs , etc.

In the latter:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IThreadEntity _threadEntityService;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IThreadEntity threadEntityService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _threadEntityService = threadEntityService;
    }

    private HomeIndexModel BuildHomeIndexModel()
    {
        var latestThreads = _threadEntityService.GetLatestThreads(amount: 10);
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

root/ Services/ ThreadService.cs

```
public class ThreadService : IThreadEntity
{
//...
    public IEnumerable<ThreadEntity> GetLatestThreads(int amount)
    {
        return GetAll().OrderByDescending<ThreadEntity> (thread => thread.CreatedAt).Take(amount);
    }
//...
}
```

I get an error here

> CS1061: `IEnumerable<ThreadEntity>` does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type `IEnumerable<ThreadEntity>` could be found.

I already checked the error code on msdn. What am I missing?
[Here](https://github.com/Zsombi55/CS_ASP.NET_Forum/tree/main/MyWebForum/WebForum) is the rest of my code if it helps.

Comment: Check if you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @arunes  Yes, I do. It was the first I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable.OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-5.0) takes 2 type parameters: it's `OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>`.

When you call `OrderByDescending<ThreadEntity>`, you're only passing 1 type parameter. The method `OrderByDescending<T>` doesn't exist, so you're getting an error.

If you want to specify type parameters, you need to specify both: `OrderByDescending<ThreadEntity, T>` where `T` is whatever type `thread.Created` is.

However, the C# compiler is good at inferring type parameters, so you should just be able to write:

```
return GetAll().OrderByDescending(thread => thread.Created).Take(a);
```

Comment: I also had a wrong attribute, it should be: ```thread.CreatedAt```. Fixed now.